# Como "recortar/fatiar" o layout da imagem com HTML e CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5, css3

tenho duvidas de como montar o layout abaixo com HTML/CSS:
[image: lAYOUT]

*Não implementei nada ainda, pois estou sem idéia de como fazer.*
Alguma sugestão?

Obrigado!

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Tem alguma coisa pronta já?

Comment: Primeiro: não são imagens "fatiadas/recortadas" são imagens sobrepostas, ela foram feitas utilizando algum software externo, como Photoshop ou Fireworks. Segundo: Sua pergunta está muito vaga, peço que especifique mais o que quer e coloque o que você já tem de código.

Comment: Pelo que parece são divs com imagens no background.

Comment: Não implementei nada ainda e @JonathanBarcela, sim, esse layout é feito no PS. Só quero uma idéia de como fazer, por exemplo aquela div central, ela é rotacionada, com skew e dentro dela tem um Background e alguns elementos de textos e menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente isso é uma `div parent` em forma de quadrado que é rodada a **45 graus**, e que depois é adicionada dentro desta uma nova `div child`, que irá conter a imagem como `background-image` que irá ser rodada a **-45 graus** para voltar novamente à rotação inicial de **0 graus**, ou vice-versa.

Por outras palavras:

```css
/* Aqui a div pai é rodada a 45 graus */
.quadrado {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* E aqui (onde está a imagem como background) volta a ser rodada novamente para a sua posição inicial */
.minhaImagem {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/QDJ7Nae.jpg);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: -50px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="quadrado">
    <div class="minhaImagem"></div>
</div>
```

No exemplo da imagem que adicionas-te juntamente com tua pergunta a imagem parece estar um pouco achatada, eu estive ali a brincar um pouco com código CSS e consegui criar o efeito do quadrado com essa rotação da maneira como já descrevi acima, porém não experimentei achatá-la, mas se desperdiçares ali um pouco de tempo de volta do código penso que conseguirás criar esse mesmo efeito. Podes também dar uma olhada [**neste artigo**](http://truquesedicascss.blogspot.pt/2015/07/imagem-hexagono-puro-css.html) que poderá te ajudar a alcançar o pretendido.

Comment: Obrigado amigo!